# How to write these equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image: .]
Everything that is underlined should be BOLD. Whatever I typed it didn't work, so please help me.

Comment: You should probably take a look at a LaTeX tutorial focusing on maths.

Comment: How such an useful comment. I didn't really know that...

Comment: @RoseHamy. So, now you know. TEX.SE is not a place to be ironic.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 4):

Just type in what you want. You can make stuff bold with `\mathbf` or if it should be bold and italic `\boldsymbol`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  E &= \mathbf{I_1} R_A + \mathbf{I_1} R_1 + \mathbf{I_1} j \omega L_1 -
  \mathbf{I_2} j \omega L_{12}\\
  U_v &= |\mathbf{U_v}|
\end{align}
If they should be bold and italic:
\begin{align}
  E &= \boldsymbol{I_1} R_A + \boldsymbol{I_1} R_1 + \boldsymbol{I_1} j \omega L_1 -
  \boldsymbol{I_2} j \omega L_{12}\\
  U_v &= |\boldsymbol{U_v}|
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa which other way to set math both bold and italic do you know?

Comment: @campa thanks for the explanations on that. I always wondered what `\pmb` should mean. Maybe I should go read a tutorial on maths as well.

Comment: @campa: It's \bm  which is the eponymous command of the package, I'd say…